# Discrete Math Compositions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I am having trouble with these compositions.
$$T = \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,c), (b,d), (c,d), (d,a), (d,b)\}$$
$$U = \{(a,a), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d), (c,a), (d,d)\}$$

I need to find $T \circ T$, $U \circ T$, and $T \circ U$.

My problem is when I get down to, for example $U \circ T$ where $(d,a)$ corresponds with both $(a,a)$ and $(a,c)$. This seems to happen for everyone of these problems. Is it even possible to take the composition of these?

Comment: What is your definition of composition with set elements?  What are the functions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "$(d,a)$ corresponds with both $(a,a)$ and $(a,c)$". $~$ What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to find these compositions.

$$\begin{align}
U\circ T ~&\mathop{:=}~ \{(x,z): \exists y~((x,y)\in T \,\wedge\, (y,z)\in U)\}
\\T &= \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,c), (b,d), (c,d), (d,a), (d,b)\}
\\U &= \{(a,a), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d), (c,a), (d,d)\}
\\U\circ T &= \{(a,a), (a,c), (a,d), \ldots\textsf{et cetera}\}
\end{align}$$

For instance $(a,c)\in U\circ T$ because $(a,b)\in T$ and $(b,c)\in U$.   As long as there is *at least one* such transition, the element appears in the composition.

Can you find the rest?

Comment: Yes, thank you.